# getting the result in an order by specific coulmn and its count of frequency in a day

Tags: mysql

I have this below table in which there is the data, so the DDL of the table is shown below and I am 
using MySQL as a database

```
create table t_log
(
    log_id bigint auto_increment
        primary key,
    p_id varchar(14) null,
    date_time datetime null,
    description varchar(1024) null,
    request_type varchar(30) null,
    status nyint(1) null    
)
charset=utf8;
```

Now I need to prepare the query in such a way such that for a particular date_time  I can group all the request_type

for example, today is 11-March-2020 so I can have an output like that

```
date_time        request_type   count 
11-March-2020     TYPE-1          20
11March-2020      TYPE-2          40
```

Please advise how can I achieve the same

Comment: Nyint? That works?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that date_time contains a date *and time*, so we have to truncate it to time only for grouping. In this case the query as simple as

```sql
SELECT DATE(date_time), request_type, COUNT(*) 
FROM t_log
WHERE DATE(date_time) = CURDATE()
GROUP BY 1, 2 -- here you can mention column numbers from select clause
```

Answer (score 0):

To get count of frequency in a day you need to do group by and as i can see your desired result you have to do group by with date_time and request_type. You also can sort using date_time and request_type as you have asked. Please try this query. It might help you

```
SELECT date_time,request_type, count(*)
FROM t_log
GROUP BY  date_time,request_type
ORDER BY date_time,request_type
```